# Get rid of a jni resolve warning about java.lang.PanwHooks on java.exe startup

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Every time I use `java.exe`, there is this warning:

```
PowerShell > java -version
[0.052s][warning][jni,resolve] Re-registering of platform native method: java.lang.PanwHooks.NativeMethodEntry(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V from code in a different classloader
java version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

No matter the JDK version. It's the same behavior whether it's `jdk1.8.0_211`, `jdk-11.0.14`, `jdk-17.0.2` or `jdk-18.0.2`. Same for OpenJDK 1.8, 11, 17 and 18.

I can not find where is the setting that is used that makes this happen. Any advice will be much appreciated.

The environment is windows 10.

Comment: It looks like java is running with an agent that redefines the method. Do you have the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` set by any chance? (try `echo $Env:JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`)

Comment: This variable is not set. Furthermore, I checked all the PATH entries and the other env variables for my account, the admin account, and the system. Is there a way to get more verbosity to troubleshoot? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. You could try running `java -Xlog:all --version > output.txt` and then try to see if you can find anything about `PanwHooks` in that.

Comment: The review of the output shows nothing suspect in terms of double loading: https://pastebin.com/kr02ED83

Answer (score 13):

It looks like it's loading a native library on VM startup as well:

```
[0.009s][info][os       ] attempting shared library load of C:\Program Files\Palo Alto Networks\Traps\cyjagent.dll
```

which looks like a Java agent.

The 'Panw' in `PanwHooks` seems to stand for Palo Alto Networks, which seems to be an antivirus software. i.e. this antivirus software seems to be injecting a dll which is a java agent, into the JVM process, which then produces this warning.

You should be able to suppress the warning with `-Xlog:jni+resolve=off` (but I realize that's not ideal).

Comment: This information saved my day. I tried to compile something with GraalVM and got a error message like this "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Java_java_lang_PanwHooks_NativeMethodEntry". Deactivating Palo Alto Cortex XDR resolve the problem.